# Gilde: How check if image is cached by url?

Tags: android-glide

I used Glide to load image from url into ImageView in android, I want to check if image url is already cached?

- If cached: I do action 1.
- If not: I do action 2.
  but I have yet to find the answer, someone can help me?

I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Glide checks multiple layers of caches before starting a new request for an image:

1. Active resources - Is this image displayed in another View right now?
2. Memory cache - Was this image recently loaded and still in memory?
3. Resource - Has this image been decoded, transformed, and written to the disk cache before?
4. Data - Was the data this image was obtained from written to the disk cache before?

The first two steps check to see if the resource is in memory and if so, return the image immediately. The second two steps check to see if the image is on disk and return quickly, but asynchronously.

If all four steps fail to find the image, then Glide will go back to the original source to retrieve the data